# Infinite streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

Say I have a function, for example the old favourite

```
def factorial(n:Int) = (BigInt(1) /: (1 to n)) (_*_)
```

Now I want to find the biggest value of `n` for which `factorial(n)` fits in a Long. I could do

```
(1 to 100) takeWhile (factorial(_) <= Long.MaxValue) last
```

This works, but the 100 is an arbitrary large number; what I really want on the left hand side is an infinite stream that keeps generating higher numbers until the `takeWhile` condition is met.

I've come up with

```
val s = Stream.continually(1).zipWithIndex.map(p => p._1 + p._2)
```

but is there a better way?

(I'm also aware I could get a solution recursively but that's not what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
Stream.from(1)
```

creates a stream starting from 1 and incrementing by 1. It's all in the [API docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$.html).

Comment: `Stream` is deprecated since 2.13.0. Use `LazyList` instead. So this would be `LazyList.from(1)`.

Answer (score 31):

## A Solution Using Iterators

You can also use an `Iterator` instead of a `Stream`. The `Stream` keeps references of all computed values. So if you plan to visit each value only once, an iterator is a more efficient approach. The downside of the iterator is its mutability, though.

There are some nice convenience methods for creating `Iterator`s defined on its [companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator$.html).

#### Edit

Unfortunately there's no short (library supported) way I know of to achieve something like

```
Stream.from(1) takeWhile (factorial(_) <= Long.MaxValue) last
```

The approach I take to advance an `Iterator` for a certain number of elements is `drop(n: Int)` or `dropWhile`:

```
Iterator.from(1).dropWhile( factorial(_) <= Long.MaxValue).next - 1
```

The `- 1` works for this special purpose but is not a general solution. But it should be no problem to implement a `last` method on an `Iterator` using pimp my library. The problem is taking the last element of an infinite Iterator  could be problematic. So it should be implemented as method like `lastWith` integrating the `takeWhile`.

An ugly workaround can be done using `sliding`, which is implemented for `Iterator`:

```
scala> Iterator.from(1).sliding(2).dropWhile(_.tail.head < 10).next.head
res12: Int = 9
```

Comment: I'm wondering what the equivalent for Iterator would be of `Stream.from(1) takeWhile (factorial(_) <= Long.MaxValue) last`, to give the answer 20?

Answer (score 4):

as @ziggystar pointed out, `Streams` keeps the list of previously computed values in memory, so using `Iterator` is a great improvment.

to further improve the answer, I would argue that "infinite streams", are usually computed (or can be computed) based on pre-computed values. if this is the case (and in your factorial stream it definately is), I would suggest using `Iterator.iterate` instead.

would look roughly like this:

```
scala> val it = Iterator.iterate((1,BigInt(1))){case (i,f) => (i+1,f*(i+1))}
it: Iterator[(Int, scala.math.BigInt)] = non-empty iterator
```

then, you could do something like:

```
scala> it.find(_._2 >= Long.MaxValue).map(_._1).get - 1
res0: Int = 22
```

or use @ziggystar `sliding` solution...

another easy example that comes to mind, would be fibonacci numbers:

```
scala> val it = Iterator.iterate((1,1)){case (a,b) => (b,a+b)}.map(_._1)
it: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator
```

in these cases, your'e not computing your new element from scratch every time, but rather do an O(1) work for every new element, which would improve your running time even more.

Answer (score 1):

The original "factorial" function is not optimal, since factorials are computed from scratch every time. The simplest/immutable implementation using memoization is like this:

```
val f : Stream[BigInt] = 1 #:: (Stream.from(1) zip f).map { case (x,y) => x * y }
```

And now, the answer can be computed like this:

```
println( "count: " + (f takeWhile (_<Long.MaxValue)).length )
```

Answer (score 0):

The following variant does not test the current, but the *next* integer, in order to find and return the last valid number:

```
Iterator.from(1).find(i => factorial(i+1) > Long.MaxValue).get
```

Using `.get` here is acceptable, since `find` on an infinite sequence will never return `None`.